# Cómo hacer para mandar un mail con copia oculta desde PHP

Tags: php, formularios, email

Bueno, mi problema es que estoy usando un PHP de un template que compré para hacer un formulario, pero no logro descifrar cómo modificarlo para que cuando el usuario envíe su consulta, no solo le llegue al mail recipiente, sino que se envíe una copia a otros correos.

Les dejo el PHP que estoy usando

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

```
<?php

$to = 'hello@misito.com'; 


$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($email) && isset($name) && isset($tel) && isset($subject) 
&& isset($message) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

 // detect & prevent header injections
$test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
  exit;
}
}

$body = <<<EMAIL
ASUNTO : $subject

HOLA MI NOMBRE ES, $name.

$message

DE : $name
TEL : $tel
MAIL : $email

EMAIL;


$header = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

//
 // mail( $to , $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], $headers );
 mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
  //      ^
  //  Replace with your email 
}?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la parte de `$header` que tienes, debes agregarle el CC/BCC, siguiendo tu código:

```
$header = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
'Cc: tumail@dominio.com' . "\r\n" .  // esto sería copia normal
'Bcc: tumail@dominio.com' . "\r\n" . // esto sería copia oculta
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

[Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) tienes el manual de la función `mail` y su uso (en el Ejemplo #4 verías lo que necesitas). Igualmente te recomiendo utilizar [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) si vas a trabajar más con correos.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, intenté haciendo esto y funcionó!

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! 
La verdad es que como no estoy tan familiarizada con el PHP, no me quise arriesgar a usar otro PHP o a hacer uno desde cero, ya que no es mi fuerte. Por eso preferí editar el del template, porque ya sé que funciona. Muchas gracias nuevamente!!

Comment: Otra pregunta, con este sistema de agregar CC al header puedo agregar para que haga una copia a dos correos, y no solo a uno? Intenté recién escribiéndolo dos veces, pero llegan como spam, y con un solo CC llegan correctamente.

Comment: Podría ser `tumail@dominio.com, tumail2@dominio.com` dentro del primer `Cc` o dos líneas de `Cc`. Depende del hosting

Comment: Gracias, ya pude hacerlo! Puse un correo detrás de otro, separado por comas, pero como Bcc en vez de Cc. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Agrega a los headers:
Bcc: email_de_copia.

En este caso:

```
$header = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .'Bcc: ' . $_POST["otro_email"] . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Answer (score -2):

Agrega esto

```
$headers .= "Bcc: $email_copia\r\n";
```

Comment: Hola Oswuell, como te ponía en otra respuesta: las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen servir de ayuda a los usuarios. Deberías añadir una pequeña descripción de cómo o por qué el código sugerido funciona. Lee [answer] para más información.